# Searching for an example of sequence $(u_n)$ such that

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}(u_{n+1}-u_n)=l\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{u_n}{n}=l$.

I found the example of $u_n=\ln(n)$ but I want another concrete example more exotic !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: $u_n=9$ for any $n$.

Comment: How about $u_n=n$?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, take $u_{n}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ for some arbitrary $a_n$ then $l$ would be $lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}$

Answer (score 1):

By [Stolz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) You only need to satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_{n+1}-u_n)=l$. The other limit will be satisfied automatically.

To produce examples you can start with any known limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ and put $u_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$